# C++ source code for bitcoin miner software?

Tags: mining-software

Does anyone know where to get the C++ source code of one workable bitcoin miner?

Answer (score 2):

Two popular Bitcoin miners, [BFGMiner](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer) and [CGMiner](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer) are open source and written in C++. The source code repositories for both are linked.